# How can i configure Expo push token to send Notifications to Multiple devices at the same time with a single click

Tags: reactjs, react-native, push-notification, expo

I have come so many articles and videos on integrating expo push notification ,But at the end of every video an expo tokens is retrieved, this token is used to send notifications to a **specified device** ,Since this is going to be very repetitive when i have alot of devices ,is there a way of getting all tokens and storing then maybe on firebase then with a single click send a notifications to **all the devices** ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe loop through the retrieved tokens